# A reference for Maass cusp forms

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms

Can anyone tell me a good reference book/article where I can find the theory of Maass cusp forms over any congruence subgroup? Many thanks for considering my request.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you add [tag:reference-request] to your tags.

Comment: "Introduction to the Spectral Theory of Automorphic Forms" by Iwaniec.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference!